# Make image resize when user resizes layout

Tags: javascript, css

**I don't want anything '100%' to fit the parent div.** The image might be a tiny square inside the div or a huge square inside the div. What I want is for the dimensions to be respected whenever the user scales the page. I tried with percentages but the image always seemed somewhat displaced despite the mathematical logic:

`div 100%  --- div dimensions in px
image X   --- image dimensions in px`

So I'm wondering if there is another way of keeping the image to resize while `resize:both` also does not work. Does anyone know how to do this?
(tagging javascript because I can use it if needed)

Comment: Post your html / css

Comment: @Amit my code is just this. A BIG rectangle div with little divs inside. Each one of the little divs has a image with height and width inherit. Then the little divs can vary in height and width compared to the BIG div.  **I don't want them to be 100%** but just to keep their dimension ratio when the user resizes.

Comment: @Fane how would you expect it to work on page load on different screen sizes? A 250px wide image loaded on a 500px screen is 50% width, but the same image on a 750px screen is 33.33% of the width.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan because I keep a ratio of the image in the database in comparison to the original dimensions of the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U could add some table or div where is your image with attribute Width (width="99%") and let it go :)

Advanced help: [Link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/), good luck !